# Synonymise [objective-c-runtime] with [objective-c]

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

The tag [objective-c-runtime](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/objective-c-runtime) has 3 questions:

- [UIScrollView Category utility function for auto sizing contentSize](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/68291/uiscrollview-category-utility-function-for-auto-sizing-contentsize) (0 answers)
- [Dynamically setting unknown properties of a subclass from parent class in Objective-C](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/48703/dynamically-setting-unknown-properties-of-a-subclass-from-parent-class-in-object) (1 answer)
- [Generic class for displaying UIAlertView / UIAlertController on iOS](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/67378/generic-class-for-displaying-uialertview-uialertcontroller-on-ios) (1 answer)

They all happen to be tagged with [objective-c](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/objective-c).

I propose that [objective-c-runtime](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/objective-c-runtime) be synonymised with [objective-c](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/objective-c), with [objective-c](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/objective-c) being the parent tag.

For reference, Stack Overflow has the tags separate, and Programmers.SE doesn't even have the tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These tags should not be synonymised.

I will double check the [objective-c-runtime](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/objective-c-runtime)-tagged questions and be certain that they are tagged correctly, but synonymising these tags would actually be quite harmful.

From the Objective-C runtime wiki:

> The Objective-C runtime is a runtime support library provided with an implementation of the Objective-C language. Its API allows dynamically creating and configuring classes at runtime, as well as introspecting existing classes, methods, properties, and method implementations.
>
> Very few Objective-C development tasks require interacting with the
>   runtime:
>
> - Introspecting the runtime environment, for example to produce a live    class browser or graph the relationships between classes or
>     objects    at runtime.
> - Creating a proxy object to interact with the message forwarding    machinery.
> - Dynamically creating classes and methods at runtime, for example, to    support a scripting interface.
> - Optimization hacks for repeated message sends, such as hoisting the    method lookup out of the loop and calling the implementing function
>     directly.
> - Writing an application without using Objective-C, such as C or C++

That all of the [objective-c-runtime](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/objective-c-runtime) questions are also tagged [objective-c](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/objective-c) is only by chance.

As the tag wiki comments, we might need to tap into the Objective-C runtime when we're writing a C or C++ application.  I'm not sure exactly why in those languages...

However, [this answer of mine on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27030181/2792531) shows a case of using the Objective-C runtime with Swift.  If I were to turn the code from that answer into a Code Review question, I'd tag it with [swift](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/swift)[objective-c-runtime](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/objective-c-runtime)[ios](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios)[uikit](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uikit) probably.